# d3.js Adding elements to pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ember.js, charts, pie-chart

I'm trying to update a pie chart with new data that can have more or less elements to show and new values. Removing arcs and updating values (with the same number of elements) is OK.

The problem is when adding new arcs: the pie transitions but it leaves blanks where the new arcs should be and draws some arcs outside the pie.

Here is **how I create the pie** (ommitting arcTween function, mouseovers, clicks, etc.)

```
    svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

    let pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value( function(d) { return d; })
            .sort(null);

    let arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(innRadius)
            .outerRadius(outRadius);

    svg.append('g')
         .attr('class', 'donut-chart')
         .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 1.75) +')');

    svg.select('.donut-chart')
         .selectAll('.donut-arc')
         .data(pie(values))
         .enter()
         .append('g')
         .attr('class', 'donut-arc _selected_');

    svg.selectAll('.donut-arc')
         .append('path')
         .attr('fill', function(d, i) { 
            if ( scale === 'linear') return color(d.value);
            return color(labels[i]); 
         })
         .attr('d', arc)
         .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

    svg.selectAll('.donut-arc')
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'labelText')
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
          d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (outRadius + 75);
         return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (outRadius + 30);
        })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
          var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
          d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (outRadius + 75);
          return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (outRadius + 20);
      })
      .text(function(d, i) {
          return labels[i];
      })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
        var rads = ((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2) + d.startAngle + 10;
        if ( (rads > 7 * Math.PI / 4 && rads < Math.PI / 4) || (rads > 3 * Math.PI / 4 && rads < 5 * Math.PI / 4) ) {
          return "middle";
        } else if (rads >= Math.PI / 4 && rads <= 3 * Math.PI / 4) {
            return "start";
        } else if (rads >= 5 * Math.PI / 4 && rads <= 7 * Math.PI / 4) {
            return "end";
        } else {
            return "middle";
        }
      });

    svg.selectAll('path').transition().attrTween("d", arcTween);
```

And this is **how I update the pie**:

```
    let paths = svg.datum(values).selectAll('path').data(pie);
    let textLabels = svg.selectAll('.labelText').data(pie(values));

    paths.enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) { 
            if ( scale === 'linear') return color(d.value);
            return color(labels[i]); 
         })
         .attr('d', arc)
         .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

    textLabels.enter()
        .append('text');

    paths.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween('d', arcTween);

    textLabels.transition()
        .duration(1250)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
          d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (outRadius + 75);
          return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (outRadius + 30);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
          var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
          d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (outRadius + 75);
          return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (outRadius + 20);
      })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
        var rads = ((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2) + d.startAngle + 10;
        if ( (rads > 7 * Math.PI / 4 && rads < Math.PI / 4) || (rads > 3 * Math.PI / 4 && rads < 5 * Math.PI / 4) ) {
          return "middle";
        } else if (rads >= Math.PI / 4 && rads <= 3 * Math.PI / 4) {
            return "start";
        } else if (rads >= 5 * Math.PI / 4 && rads <= 7 * Math.PI / 4) {
            return "end";
        } else {
            return "middle";
        }
       })
       .text(function(d, i) {
          return labels[i];
       });

  paths.exit().remove();
  textLabels.exit().remove();

  svg.transition().attr({width: width, height: height});
```

What am I doing wrong?

This pie-chart is an Ember component and its full code can be found [here](https://github.com/ElXaxe/Barcelona-Dashboard/blob/libraries/client-app/app/components/pie-chart.js)

**And [here](https://barcelona-dashboard.herokuapp.com/libraries-visits) you can find the working app**. Click on any district to show the pie chart.

Comment: you will get better answers, if you can put this up on a working fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, never made a fiddle. I've linked the app URL so you can see it working.

Comment: You probably don't need separate code for creating the pie and updating it. Your code here is practically identical, and I think you could rewrite it as a single function that takes in data and draws or updates the pie. Use enter, update, and exit selections to control different behavior on new and updating elements. https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/ Your problem will probably go away if you do this, or at least it will be easier to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found the solution!

I missed a transform to locate the center for new arcs appearing in the pie. Also I was not selecting the proper elements. For example: selectAll('.labelText') was wrong. You better make selectAll('text') to enter new data.

Thanks for all your answers!